# History of 5 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

**New Series**

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1987- A U.S. Federal Court ruled in favour of the Agudas Chassidei Chabad in a case surrounding a priceless collection of Jewish books that had been pilfered from the Chabad-Lubavitch library.

The ruling hinged on the idea that a Rebbe is not a private individual, but a communal figure and his possessions are not personal either. The Lubavitcher Rebbe dedicated this date annually as a time to increase Torah study and to purchase Torah books.

More details: http://tinyurl.com/254nhuq

Comment: ChabadRabbi, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this historical note! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Here is the sublink from the aforelinked site: http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day_cdo/aid/233829/jewish/Sefarim-victory.htm

Answer (score 4):

On 5 Teves 3339, the Jewish community in Babylonia received the news of the destruction of the Beis Hamikdash (Ezek. 33:21).

According to R' Shimon (Rosh Hashanah 18b), the fast of Teves (called צום העשירי in Zech. 8:19) should actually be on this date; even though we don't follow this opinion in practice, we do mention the event in the Selichos of the 10th of Teves.

Answer (score 2):

5 Teveis 5295 - Roman Emperor Charles V ordered the auto-da-fe of Rav Shlomo Molcho in Mantua, Italy

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25788