# Was Shlomo Molcho a great kabbalist or a false messiah?

Tags: history, messiah, mysticism-kabbalah

History records that a Portuguese Marano, Diego Peres (born 1500), after being spurned by Jewish adventurist David Reuveni, circumcised himself, changed his name to Shlomo Molcho, and went on a mission to convince Maranos everywhere to return to Judaism.  History records, also, that he correctly predicted a flood in Rome and an earthquake in Portugal, gaining him the respect and protection from the Inquisition from Pope Clement VII.  He later fled to Turkey and Eretz Israel and was known to be a student of Rabbi Joseph Karo, among others.  In 1532 he was burned at the stake by Emperor Charles V of the Holy Roman Empire.  See, e.g. Dimont, Max I., "Jews, God and History." Secular historians have named Molcho as a false messiah.  Yet in some Hasidic circles -- especially those of Galicia and Hungary -- he is revered as a saint and Kabbalist.  Which version is true?

Comment: Did you just ask whether the secular historians or the chassidic tradition is True? I can already see where the answers are going to go...

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't mention any Hasidic veneration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Molcho

Comment: [להחכם השלם הקדוש רבינו שלמה מלכו נר"ו](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/39001) (from a book 200 years after his death)

Comment: @ba Ya, here too: http://rabbishimon.com/tzadikim/showz.php?p=molcho.htm

Comment: @DoubleAA:  I found out from a Muncacher that they hold him quite highly.  He was surprised that historians considered Molcho a pseudo-messiah.  If you read Dimont's book, or the Jewish Encyclopedia, he seems to be quite colorful, very lucky, and a bit off. So when I saw the Prague Museum exhibit (which includes Molcho's flag) with my Muncacher friend, he was seriously impressed as was I, but for different reasons.  I'm looking to resolve these issues.

Comment: Reuveni was thought to be Messiah by area Jews, initially, when he arrived in Spain/Portugal under protection of the Vatican.  The Vatican believed his story about having an army of Jews that would open up a second front against the Arabs in the Crusades, and sent him to visit kings to get financing.  As a courtesy, they temporarily stayed the Inquisition, resulting in joy in the Jewish world.  This caused Peres/Molcho to try to see Reuveni.  Reuveni, I believe, was a fraud, and didn't want too much attention from local Maranos.

Comment: http://revach.net/stories/gedolim-biographies/Rav-Shlomo-Molcho-Hyd-A-Savior-And-A-Martyr/3214

Comment: Actually, I just happened to find this: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4971&st=&pgnum=12 (15 lines from the start of the new paragraph)

Comment: "Was Shlomo Molcho a great kabbalist or a false messiah?" Is there any reason he can't be both? No one complains that Bar Kochva was a terrible person for thinking he may be the messiah.

Comment: I don't get the question. How do you want people to answer? By listing kabbalaists who believed one thing and historians who believed the other?

Answer (score 8):

[R' Chaim Vital](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21924&pgnum=51) writes that he used "Practical Kabbalah" inappropriately, and there is a tradition that one who uses it inappropriately (like if one is ritually impure from a corpse) will either get sick (he or his descendant) or he (or his descendant) will convert out. He says that **Rabbi** Shlomo Molcho (emphasis mine) was an example of one who used "Practical Kabbalah" and was uprooted from the world.

However, [the Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4583&pgnum=280) said that he was a great Mekubal, he had Mesirus Nefesh to debate with the Pope, and he wanted to bring the Geula. He failed, but merited giving his life Al Kiddush Hashem (which is something the Beis Yosef wanted his whole life).

Comment: Is the Lubavitcher Rebbe arguing that he didn't misuse kabbalah, or just emphasizing the good he did?

Comment: I must say I'm rather glad the Beis Yosef never gave his life up early Al Kiddush Hashem. Seems living Al Kiddush Hashem was much more effective.

Comment: Interestingly enough, R. Chaim Vital himself wrote a book where he describes using practical kabbalah himself! See: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2010/07/r-chaim-vital-and-his-unknown-work.html

Answer (score 5):

In igros Ramchal of machon Ramchal, letter 8, he brings a testimony of Rav Rafael Kimchi, of Tsfas, who says that the Arizal and  "The Holy Mekubal" Rav Shlomo Molcho are two examples of people who no one can deny their teachings and actions, and had revelation of angels.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites)
Sam and thanks for this first answer. Hope to see you around !

Answer (score 3):

The Shach mentions the way the Reb Shlomo Molcho had his Tzitzis as a true source. The Beis Yosef's Sefer, Magid Mesharim speaks of him as a Tzaddik. The Arizal, although criticizing the use of practical Kabbalah, does not speak of him as a charlatan. Rabbi Joselman of Rosheim thought his approach was rash but also not a false messiah.

Comment: Who is Rabbi Joselman of Rosheim? What do all the other references have to do with the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josel_of_Rosheim

Comment: @ShmuelBrin His diary is around. I think I recall seeing it in a biannual journal, the name of which skips my mind now.

Comment: "had his Tzitzis as a true source"

Comment: @shmuelBrin not really sure why I said Shach, but the [Magen Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.11.22) quotes the Lechem Chamudos on this.